# The second law for rotations

Tags: mathematical-physics

Is Newton's second law for rotations derived from his three laws of motion, or is it an independent axiom of physics?

Comment: You mean rotary generalization of $ T = I \theta ^{''} $ from linear $ F = m x^{''}? $

Comment: @Narasimham: Yep. Or from any combination of the three laws of linear motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_laws_of_motion)

The by (now classical) rotary/straight line equilibrium of torques and forces of general dynamical motion were derived by Euler. For example, they can be used to predict rigid body motion in zero gravity due to applied external forces and moments.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show the derivation, link to a document where this derivation can be found, or point me to an appropriate source?

Comment: There is great deal of literature. I myself read only about  Euler's rigid body rotations $ \phi,\psi,\theta $